# How do I add a parameter ton my path symfon4?

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, twig, symfony4

Hello im trying to give an id parameter to my path however when i click on the button to go to my url with the id there is an error and the url shows /x istead of an Id.

I already tried this

```
<a href="{{ path('confirm_selected_cours', {'id': cour.id }) }}" class="btn btn-primary float-right" role="button">S'inscrire dans ce cours</a>
```

but it did not work

here is my code

```
<ul class="list-group">
 {% for cour in cours %}
     <li class="list-group-item list-group-item-warning">
         {{ cour.title }}
         <a href="{{ path('confirm_selected_cours', {'id': cour.id }) }}" class="btn btn-primary float-right" role="button">S'inscrire dans ce cours</a>
    </li>
 {% endfor %}
```

and this is in my Controller 
   `/**
     * @Route("/etudiant/inscription-cours/{id}", name="confirm_selected_cours")
     */

```
public function confirmRegistrationCours($id)
{
     $repoCours = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(Cours::class);
     $cours = $repoCours->find($id);
     return $this->render('student/show_selected_cours.html.twig', [
         'cour' => $cours
     ]);
```

}`

Comment: I forgot to say that when i enter the url with an id by myslef the page show itself with all the information

Answer (score 0):

I was using id instead of ID so im adding this because i must use 30 characters to post